# In this Tensorflow model, what model parameters are changing from one epoch to the next?

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras

To make my question more specific based on the comments, which model parameters are changing from epoch to epoch? The starting weights?

I'm reviewing this Tensorflow tutorial here: 
https://codelabs.developers.google.com/codelabs/tensorflow-lab2-computervision/index.html

As the model is trained, I see there are 5 epochs each with different accuracy. But I'm not sure what is changing from epoch to epoch and how the final model is determined based on these epochs. Here is a code snippet of the model creation and training.

```
model = tf.keras.models.Sequential([tf.keras.layers.Flatten(), 
                                    tf.keras.layers.Dense(128, activation=tf.nn.relu), 
                                    tf.keras.layers.Dense(10, activation=tf.nn.softmax)])

model.compile(optimizer = tf.train.AdamOptimizer(),
              loss = 'sparse_categorical_crossentropy',
              metrics=['accuracy'])

model.fit(training_images, training_labels, epochs=5)
```

Any help would be much appreciated. Thank you!

Comment: This seems like an off-topic question to me. It’s also quite broad/vague.

Answer (score 0):

The way the model changes epoch to epoch is actually what makes machine learning even work. You should probably learn the inner workings of some basic models (such as the kNN) that aren't restricted to specific libraries before jumping in to coding neural networks on your own.

Essentially, the model trains between each epoch, optimizing its parameters (i.e. modifying the mathematical functions it applies to each neuron in each layer) to improve its accuracy over time.